# Use Kubernetes Ingress with dynamic parameters to web API

Tags: c#, nginx, kubernetes, asp.net-web-api, nginx-ingress

I am having a problem using Kubernetes Ingress with a ASP.NET core web API.

Lets say I have a web API with three controllers (simplified code to demonstrate three routes /, /ep1, /ep2):

```
endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("##");
});

endpoints.MapGet("/ep1", async context =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("1");
});

endpoints.MapGet("/ep2", async context =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("2");
});
```

What I want is to define an ingress rule that will pass the internal route to the application:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhost.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: myservice
            port:
              number: 80
```

Then what I expect to happen is that browsing to myhost.com/ will return "##", myhost.com/ep1 will return "1" and myhost.com/ep2 will return "2"
However, all three routes return "##"

Am I doing something wrong while configuring the ingress? Is it something that even possible when using ingress rules? If not, how do you create a controller that is using dynamic parameters? Let's say I want a web API that returns the amount in bank for some user ID, when specifying its ID in the GET path: myhost.com/balance/1312323, how can I implement this using a web API and ingress rules with Kubernetes?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routing within the app should be handled by the app. So, there should be no need to define dynamic paths. Try this.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhost.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: myservice
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed solve my problem as I presented it in the first place. However it seems like in this way there's no meaning to the ingress http routing. What if I have two services that I want to route? Example: myhost.com/app1/ep1 will be routed to service "app1" and the app will handle the ep1 routing. myhost.com/app2/ep1 will be routed to service "app2" and the app will handle ep1 routing. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, then you will  define two items under paths. one for each service. Example: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/service/networking/simple-fanout-example.yaml

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get 404 error. That means that the app is found but internal routing (ep1) does not work. I'll try to simplify my question: what I need is that myhost.com/app/ep1 will route to the ep1 route configured inside the application. and '/app' will route to the application itself.

Comment: try removing the rewrite-target annotation

Comment: This still doesn't work. I have removed all annotations. The rule now has - path: /app and pathType: Prefix. Going to myhost.com/app/ep1 returns 404.