# Two endponts into one service with Kubernetes Nginx Ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am trying to reproduce this configuration from regular NGinx in Kubernetes NGinx ingress:

```
location /addresslookup/ {
    ...        
    proxy_pass          https://fmt-address-lookup-service:5005/addresslookup/;
}

location /geocode/ {
    ...
    proxy_pass          https://fmt-address-lookup-service:5005/geocode/;
}
```

Basically I want two different external endpoints to feed through to two different paths on the ***same*** Kubernetes service. I can see how to setup the two endpoints and point them to the service:

```
 rules:
  - host: api2.findmytea.co.uk
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /addresslookup/(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: fmt-address-lookup
          servicePort: 5004
      - path: /geocode/(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: fmt-address-lookup
          servicePort: 5004
```

But I cannot find an example of how to make it direct to a certain path on the service.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need just one path to redirect traffic to your service.
Routing within the app should be handled by the app. So, there should be no need to define multiple paths in ingress for the same service.

Here are multiple examples (NodeJS/Express) how an app can handle internal routing
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Refer to my response to a similar thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67975782/2777988

Comment: But, if you want to point these two paths to the same service(in case of other ingress rules) and you need to do this without additional path implementation you can use regex functionality in the ingress.

Comment: Thanks! What I needed was a single path: "- path: /(addresslookup/(.*)|geocode)" and to understand how the routing really works, which you helped me do.